# .NET Bearer Token cant [Authorize] always 401 Unauthorized

Tags: unauthorized, authorize

I'm very newbie in .NET and trying to implemented Bearer Token in some WebAPI:

My Controller:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    [Route("/api")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("{clientKey}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(string clientKey)
    {
        SQLDataResult response = null;

        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientKey", clientKey));

        response = await new SQLDataContext().StoredProcedureExecuteReaderAsync<SQLDataResult>("ClientCheck", parameters);

        if (response == null)
        {
            response = new SQLDataResult();
            return Ok(response);
        }
        else
        {
            var token = new JwtTokenBuilder()
                .AddSecurityKey(JwtSecurityKey.Create("imarh-secret-key"))
                .AddSubject("imarh")
                .AddIssuer("imarh.Security.Bearer")
                .AddAudience("imarh.Security.Bearer")
                .AddClaim("MembershipId", "111")
                .AddExpiry(1)
                .Build();
            return Ok(token.Value);
        }
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost] 
    [Route("/api/get/{clientID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ClientAssign(string clientID)
    {
        SQLDataResult response = null;

        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientID", clientID));
        response = await new SQLDataContext().StoredProcedureExecuteReaderAsync<SQLDataResult>("ClientAssign", parameters);

        if (response == null)
            response = new SQLDataResult();

        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Token is getting correctly. When I remove [Authorize] attribute from second API I will get correct result from the database. But when return and pass generated token in Authorization header I always getting 401 Unauthorized with no any result.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this can happen in different cases, but in mine the only one that fixes the problem was:

```
// app.UseMvc();
```

in **Startup.cs**